# Why can't roll back to the savepoint at the second time in Transaction-SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I created a table named "TestTable"

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   Value INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

And then I insert into the table some records as following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(1,1)
    SAVE TRANSACTION TS1
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
         INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(2,2)
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TS1
         --roll back to TS1 at the first time

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(4,3)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TS1
    --roll back to TS1 at the second time
```

Messages show off "Cannot roll back TS1. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found."

Then I thought is it possible roll back to the savepoint only once?

Comment: Why have you added the [tag:mysql] tag? I thought you were asking about SQL Server - they're two different products and now your question is tagged with both.

Comment: You have a lot of begin transaction without rollback or commit why ?

Answer (score 0):

this way

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.TranTest
    (
        c1      int
    )
GO

    BEGIN       TRAN    T1

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TranTest]
                   ([c1])
             VALUES
                   (1)

    SAVE        TRAN    T1

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TranTest]
                   ([c1])
             VALUES
                   (2)

    ROLLBACK    TRAN    T1
GO
```

Comment: Yeah,I intentionally made the error to want to question that why I can't roll back TS1 one more time?

Comment: TRANSACTION statement end with the COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement.